# Find the pattern to this number series!

Tags: number-sequence

OK, so here is the series of numbers:

```
1225
1540
2926
4005
5985
8856
9045
9801
11781
11935
12376
12496
12720
13041
14400
16401
17200
17226
17290
17865
18096
21528
21736
23001
23751
24220
24976
25425
26796
27000
```

Whats the pattern? And what comes next? :)

Comment: Did you make this yourself?

Comment: @Mithrandir I did. It comes from some research I have been doing into polygonal numbers, so thats a hint there. :)

Comment: Just making sure, because if you post something that you didn't make yourself without attribution, it's plagiarism. :P

Comment: Ahh I see, well yes I did make this series. I have it going as far as n=3086 right now, and calculating the next in the series as we speak. for n=3086 by the way, the number is 2269296

Comment: Just to be clear: are these for n=1, n=2, etc.?

Comment: They are. The seuence given starts with n=1.

Comment: Once this is solved you should consider adding it to the OEIS. Probably best not to do that before it's solved, though. (Of course once I see the solution I may change my mind about its appropriateness for OEIS...)

Comment: If my answer is correct then I think this (and some obvious "predecessors" to it) certainly do belong in OEIS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are (at least up to 27000) precisely the positive integers that

> are polygonal numbers in at least seven ways.

I think the next number is

> 27405.

Comment: Correct! I have the series calculated up to n = 3388, which gives all possible answers up to 2,500,000 so far, and have already submitted a pending addition to OEIS for these. :)
https://oeis.org/A275256 is where I submitted these :)

Comment: Did you also submit the corresponding sequences with (1) numbers below 7 and (2) *exactly* so many polygonal-number representations rather than *at least* so many? I think these should all be in OEIS.

Comment: I haven't yet, can do in a short while though :)